# Is there a way to disable YouTube HTML5 video player in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, html5

A few weeks ago, YouTube started showing half of their videos in HTML5 player for me. Is there a way to force it back to using Flash player only (in Chrome)?

(I'm opted out of HTML5 trial at http://www.youtube.com/html5.)

Comment: In http://www.youtube.com/html5 page click the ***Leave HTML5 Beta*** link at the bottom. Clear all browser history, cache, etc.

Comment: @Tiago I'm not in the beta, I have "Join" button, not "Leave"

Comment: try adding "&html5=false" to the end of your youtube url. This is only a temporary fix though

Comment: @Cybertox Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Switch to Opera. That worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First join the trial, and then leave it. Leaving the trial is the only way to force YouTube to remember you want the videos played in Flash, but of course to do that you have to join the trial first. It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: wow! who would you knew :D Thanks!

Comment: apparently this doesn't work anymore

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't, which is really annoying because the html5 player just doesn't work for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Here's how I enforced my dominion over Chrome: Find the file called ffmpegsumo.dll where Chrome is installed (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\30.xxxxx\ for me). Delete it or move it out of that folder. I also moved nacl_irt_*.nexe.

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn/related) if you use the Chrome browser, install [YouTube Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn/related) and specify the codec as Flash.

By default YouTube options will also change a bunch other aspects of the YouTube interface (e.g., hiding comments, video descriptions, ads, etc.). You may like this, but you may also want to modify some of this plugin behaviour if for example, you like video descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your Flash cookies. http://macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

I had the same issue, in fact I just came here because I was googling for a solution. I noticed that videos that would play in HTML5 on Chrome would play in Flash in Firefox even if I was signed in to Youtube on both browsers so I figured that it was a cookie thing. Deleting my regular Youtube cookies didn't do anything but I just cleared my Flash cookies and videos that were HTML5 are now Flash again.

Comment: I deleted data for all websites in the storage manager but still getting HTML5 videos on YouTube.

Comment: It's randomly returned for me and another deletion of my Flash cookies didn't fix it. I did find this userscript (scroll down for Chrome extension version) that can force Flash among other things, though: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002

Comment: @Bonkwisha - That userscript is exactly the solution. If I could upvote twice your comment I would.

Answer (score 0):

After leaving the trial and clearing the cache and cookies, you must also go to Chrome's Extensions page (chrome://extensions) and disable the extension "HTML5 Video for YouTube" (and possibly "YouTube Options" for good measure)

Answer (score 0):

Install the [YouTube Flash Player (Chrome version)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash%C2%AE-player-for-youtube/lajdkhdcndkniopfefocbgbkofflagpm?hl=en) / [(Firefox version)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/) extension:

> This add-on forces YouTube to play videos using Flash Player instead of the HTML5 player.

Answer (score -1):

After a whise wandering in forums I found this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-video-for-youtube/dolajcekhnohkpncmhgledbmndjpblei
This doesn't **solve** the problem, it's a workaround, but it works.